# Java Layout Manager tips

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, jframe

I created a small program which is shown in the link. And I used 
 absolute layout. But I want to try other layouts. Are there any alternative layouts to use apart from absolute layout ?
[Here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9HdE.png)

Comment: You should be able to accomplish that layout with GridBag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a different opinion, I wouldn't recommend GridBagLayout. It is the most flexible so you can do pretty much anything with it but it is pretty hard to use. A simpler way is to use a composed approach, meaning multiple panels in your main UI where each panel has its own layout. For example, for the two top components you can use a vertical BoxLayout and for the bottom part you can use a FormLayout

But the point is, it is better IMO to mix and match layouts than to use one single super flexible layout for everything. Check [this link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=166) for more info. They mention what I recommended:

> Layout Managers are often mixed together in a single frame or dialog,
>   where a top level container has its own Layout Manager (often a
>   BoxLayout or BorderLayout), and smaller parts use their own layout,
>   completely independent of the others.

Another nice tip is to use a GUI builder such as Eclipse's WindowBuilder or Netbean's Matisse; that way you don't design UIs in code, which is pretty abstract

Answer (score 0):

Use **gridbaglayout**. To properly use it, read first about **gridbagconstraints**.